# Forcing FreeMarker to always print BigDecimal value with decimal point

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker, bigdecimal

In a Spring MVC application using FreeMarker for rendering views, how do I force FreeMarker to always print BigDecimal values with decimal points?

For instance:

```
1000.12 -> 1000.12
1000    -> 1000.00
```

I tried

```
${value?string("0.##")}
```

This printed 1000.12 correctly as 1000.12 but 1000 still printed as 1000 instead of 1000.00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `${1000?string("0.00")}`?

If you need to round your numbers down use `((n * 100)?floor) / 100.0` expression

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.  1000 becomes 1000.00 and 1000.12 stays 1000.12 but 1000.4567 becomes 1000.46 (gets rounded for some reason), whereas I need 1000.45 (digits as they are).

Comment: then i suggest you using ((n * 100)?floor) / 100.0

Comment: @manish.in.java: It's because FreeMarker just uses `java.text.DecimalFormat`, and that always uses `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`. (Seems FreeMarker should allow custom `NumberFormat` implementations). Anyway, you could write `TemplateMethodModelEx` for this, and use it like `${twoDecimals(1000)}` or `${my.twoDecimals(1000)}`.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers you have provided.  I will try along the lines of your suggestions.